# jQuery gets old value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code, when I change the value in the box and click "Update", jQuery gets the old value of the input field. When I refresh the page (the new input is retained after the refresh) and click the "Update" again, then the new value is used. What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var submit_command = function(e) {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/__test',
                e.data,
                function(data) {
                    $("#result").text(data.test);
                    });
            return false;
        };
        $('a#update_parameter').bind('click', {
                                    name: "Param",
                                    test: parseFloat($('input:text[name=input_parameter]').val().replace(",", "."))
                                }, submit_command);
    });
    </script>
<div class="parameter">
    <span class="parameter_name">My Parameter</span>
    <input type="text" name="input_parameter" size=3 />
    <a href=# id="update_parameter">Update</a>
    <span id="result">?</span>
</div>
</body>
```

**Note:** Feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: @pszaba: In the server log I see that the function is sending the old value (the value from when the page first loaded). fDruga's answer solves the problem (calling a function instead of binding on load-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like this

```
$('a').click(function (){
    alert($('input[name=input_parameter]').val());
});
```

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2bt5pqxb/ - it alerts the inserted value. I hope this helps

Comment: I cannot vote up (not enough reputation), but this solves my problem. Thank you! In your answer, could you elaborate a bit why? Is it because the binding happens when the page is loaded and the data cannot be changed afterwards?

Comment: Hi, i didn't inspect what was wrong with your solution because of the server call.. I'm glad that that my answer did the trick. I'm not familiar with the way you binded the click click on the button either so i can't say what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

When updating a value and later want the new value, you need to trigger change event when updating eg:

```js
$(your_selector).val(some_value).trigger("change");
```